# CPanel bandwidth folder too big, can be deleted?

Tags: centos, cpanel

My folder which contains bandwidth usage data is getting too large. My question is if i will break something when i delete the contents of this folder. I don't realy care about the data in there because i don't check bandwidht usage for my users

or should i just move the folder to a bigger disk and create a symlink to it?

folder: `/var/cpanel/bandwidth`

Comment: too big... what is too big?

Comment: the folder has 10GB

Comment: just the bandwidth directory?  What exactly is in there?

Comment: Let me rephrase.  You should not have 10GB of data in that directory, if it is only referring to the bandwidth usage of your cpanel controlled reseller account.  Thus, you should re-examine exactly what this 10gb consists of... file by file, directory by directory.  A year's worth of 4kb reports for a single account should add up to about 1.5mb... and have you had 600 accounts for 10 years to accumulate 10GB worth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete some of the data. You might want to back it up locally, copy the data to your computer. Basically if you first back it up then delete the content it will just be like starting over with no bandwidth data yet.

However, the bandwidth folder can't really be that big, if it is then you must have a very small hard drive and it may be time for upgrading. Storage is cheap.

Try checking to see if maybe you are using more storage space elsewhere. You can do this in ssh. Something like this could help:

```
du -h | sort -rh
```

This will list the files in the directory (`du`), make it human readable (`-h`), and sort by filesize, recursive, human readable (sort -rh)